# How can I retrieve the defined namespace declarations after unmarshalling with JAX-B

Tags: xml, namespaces, jaxb

I have an XML document that includes XPath expressions that I need to use in my application.  Since I have to define the Namespaces to Jaxen, I need to retrieve the namespaces that were in the original XML document after it is unmarshalled by JAX-B.  How would I go about retrieving the declared namespaces?  Thanks.

(*Chris*)

More Info:

I need to supply the Namespaces to the JDOM/Jaxen XPath processor when applying the mappings.  (/.../ used for brevity)

```xml
<mappings set="RTE" xmlns="http://www.powerschool.com/mappings" xmlns:sif="http://www.sifinfo.org/infrastructure/2.x" xmlns:ntc="http://stumo.transcriptcenter.com">
  <mapping name="Area">
    <endpoint end="SIF" type="XML">
       <xpath>/sif:StudentRecordExchangeData/.../sif:SIF_ExtendedElement[@Name="StudentDemographicRecordExtensions"]/.../ntc:Area</xpath>
    </endpoint>
  </mapping>
</mappings>
```

Comment: Are your namespaces declared on the root element or throughout the XML document?

Comment: So, you're trying to extract the namespace associated to the 'sif' prefix from your document. But it's used in the value of the <xpath> element, so it's not really associated. I'd recommend you use a 'namespaceuri(s)' attribute in that xpath element (if more than one, you can use a comma-separated syntax or some other list syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following up on my comment above:

More specifically, the sif namepsace is not associated with any element or attribute in your XML document per-se, and therefore the declaration xmlns:sif="xxx" is immaterial, including for JAXB. It's only relevant to the application that interprets the value for mapping.endpoint.xpath.

```xml
<mappings set="RTE" xmlns="http://www.powerschool.com/mappings" >
  <mapping name="Area">
    <endpoint end="SIF" type="XML" namespaces="sif=http://www.sifinfo.org/infrastructure/2.x ntc=http://stumo.transcriptcenter.com">
       <xpath>/sif:StudentRecordExchangeData/.../sif:SIF_ExtendedElement[@Name="StudentDemographicRecordExtensions"]/.../ntc:Area</xpath>
    </endpoint>
    <!-- or: -->
    <endpoint end="SIF" type="XML">
       <namespace prefix="sif">http://www.sifinfo.org/infrastructure/2.x</namespace>
       <namespace prefix="ntc">http://stumo.transcriptcenter.com</namespace>
       <xpath>/sif:StudentRecordExchangeData/.../sif:SIF_ExtendedElement[@Name="StudentDemographicRecordExtensions"]/.../ntc:Area</xpath>
    </endpoint>
  </mapping>
</mappings>
```

Therefore I'm proposing to add the namespace declaration as explicit nodes for your application to process along with the value node, you should then be able to pass along to jaxen or any other module.

Comment: That's actually similar to what I've done as a workaround, but I really wanted to use the more intuitive syntax if possible.  I've written the same extractor using a straight SAX parser and it was trivial to get that information, so I was hoping to do the same with JAX-B.  I guess that's just a limitation of the technology.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, the jaxb objects are unmarshalled based on their namespace, so the namespace is associated with your JAXB objects. In particular, if you generated your JAXB classes from XSD, the package (jaxbObject.getCLass().getPackage() will have annotation information that includes the declared namespace.

You can do it the hard way and look up the package object and its annotation, or you can use the JAXBIntrospector from your context instance. So assuming your jaxb object is 'jaxbObject' and 'jaxbContent' is your JAXBContext instance:

```java
 JAXBIntrospector introspector = jaxbContext.createJAXBIntrospector();
 if (!introspector.isElement(jaxbObject))
     throw new JAXBException("Type '" + objectToMarshall.getClass().getName() + "' is not a JAXB object.");

 QName qname = introspector.getElementName(jaxbObject);
 if (qname == null)
     throw new JAXBException("Type '" + jaxbObject.getClass().getName()
                + "' is not a JAXB object instance.");

 String namespaceUri = qname.getNamespaceURI();
```

Comment: I believe that will effectively get the Namespace for the JAX-B Object itself, but how do I get to the namespaces that were declared in the parsed XML.  From what I'm hearing, I think you're telling me they are discarded by JAX-B, which is a pity.  It means I'll have to declare content for something that already has a place in the XML document.  Thanks for the information.

Comment: I don't believe I'm implying that. I assume the namespaces declared in the original (parsed) XML document are directly relevant to JAXB as in being directly mapped to the JAXB object (and the namespaces should be statically available from the generated classes). What 'other' namespace declaration are you expecting to find ? Unless you are referring to open-ended section of your schema (e.g. <xs:any>) and/or xjc options such as xjc:dom ?

Comment: See "More Info" on original question.

Comment: See my second tentative answer for more details.